# Search a string in a column and select that cell using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

How should I search a string in a column and then select that cell using button click event?

Comment: Counting questions... One... One. I see just one question. Which is good -- one question per question is really the proper way to do it.

Comment: haha... I am bad at math... :p

Comment: or bad at math too... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a for each loop through the range you want to look in. Once you find the cell whose value = search value use ".select" and Exit Sub.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. It's working fine. But when I have too many rows, don't you think this linear search will take more time. Is there any inbuilt function which does this faster than linear time?

Comment: You could always try linking the button to the normal search in excel (when you open the search box and search it'll bring you to the cell). I wouldn't be too worried about speed unless it's an insane amount of cells to be honest.